# Possible to use this script with media query?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, breakpoints

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I would like to know if I can use this script:

```
    //Closes nav dropdown when clicking logo
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navbar-brand").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
    });
```

with this media query `@media(max-width:767px) {}`.

Ideally, I would like the script to work in multiple browsers, and *fire the same time* as the css ONLY when the browser is 767px or less. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could campare it to `window.innerWidth`. try (not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ( $(window).innerWidth() < 767){
$(".navbar-brand").click(function(event) {
$(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
}});
```

Comment: I tried using this code and the menu does not collapse as intended.